# dynamic height cell with imageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I encountered such a problem, I have a cell in a table that stores - uilabel and uiimageview. With server images come in different sizes - square or rectangular, I have them squeeze the screen size (shrink the width and height is calculated automatically). In my HIB file uiimageview is fixing the height of 255, as I do, so that the elements uilabel was calculated its distance from the dynamic image height and not from the one that is listed in the XIB. I read a couple of guides, but do not know where the mistake.

[image]

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
CGFloat size = [self heightForImageCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"height cell = %f", size);
return size;
}


- (CGFloat)calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell:(UITableViewCell *)sizingCell {
[sizingCell setNeedsLayout];
[sizingCell layoutIfNeeded];

CGSize size = [sizingCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
return size.height + 1.0f; // Add 1.0f for the cell separator height
}


- (CGFloat)heightForImageCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static HomeTableViewBigCell *sizingCell = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sizingCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([HomeTableViewBigCell class])];
});
NSLog(@"ok 1");
[self configureImageCell:sizingCell atIndexPath:indexPath];
return [self calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell:sizingCell];
}

- (void)configureImageCell:(HomeTableViewBigCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
Article *article = [self.articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.titleLabel.text = article.title;
cell.subtitleLabel.text = article.subtitle;
cell.thematicsLabel.text = @"CUSTOM";
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[RestApiRoutes getBaseURL], article.imagePath];
NSURL *fullImagePath = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:fullImagePath
                  placeholderImage:self.placeholder options:0
                          progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {}
                         completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                             cell.imageView.image = [self resizeImage:image :CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 0)];
                         }];//0 - dynamic height
}
```

in HomeTableViewBigCell.m:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
[super layoutSubviews];
[self.contentView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
[self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];

CGRect contentImageFrame = self.imageView.frame;
contentImageFrame.origin.y = 0;
contentImageFrame.origin.x = 0;
self.imageView.frame = contentImageFrame;
}
```

very much like to understand how to make the lower elements of counting the distance from the new height of the image rather than on rigidly predetermined. Thanx!

Comment: Why don't you enable Auto-layout for your application?

Comment: @Lorenzo This auto-layout. http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout#comments